# To transform XML to HTML in table format

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I want to change this xml content to HTML table

```
    <SSI>
        <data>
            <expanded>Chemical Research</expanded><abbre>Chem. Res.</abbre>
            <expanded>Materials Journal</expanded><abbre>Mater. J.</abbre>
            <expanded>Chemical Biology</expanded><abbre>Chem. Biol.</abbre>
            <expanded>Symposium Series</expanded><abbre>Symp. Ser.</abbre>
            <expanded>Biochimica Polonica</expanded><abbre>Biochim. Pol.</abbre>
            <expanded>Chemica Scandinavica</expanded><abbre>Chem. Scand.</abbre>
        <\data>
        <data>
            <expanded>Botany</expanded><abbre>Bot.</abbre>
            <expanded>Chemical Engineering</expanded><abbre>Chem. Eng.</abbre>
            <expanded>Chemistry</expanded><abbre>Chem.</abbre>
            <expanded>Earth Sciences</expanded><abbre>Earth Sci.</abbre>
            <expanded>Microbiology</expanded><abbre>Microbiol.</abbre>
        <\data>
    <\SSI>
```

Tried with following XSL

```
      <?xml version="1.0"?>
      <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
      <xsl:template match="/">
      <html>
      <head><title>Abbreviate</title></head>
      <body>
      <table border="1">
      <tr>
      <th>Expanded</th>
      <th>Abbre</th>
      </tr>
       <xsl:for-each select="SSI/data">
       <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="expanded"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="abbre"/></td>
       </tr>
       </xsl:for-each>
      </table>
      </body></html>
      </xsl:template>
      </xsl:stylesheet>
```

I got only the first entry of data tag in HTML Table format

```
    Expanded               Abbre  
    -----------           --------------------  
    Chemical Research     Chem. Res  
    Botany                Bot.
```

how can get all the values in HTMl???

Comment: use code formating option ({}-button to format your source code, so that we can see it correctly!

Comment: Are your closing tags the wrong way around in your original code or is it just a copying error? (I.e. `<\data>` instead of the correct `</data>`)

Comment: I don't know if this is a copy and paste XML, but you got \ (BACKslahes) in your closing data and SSI tags...

Comment: its just a copying error

Comment: are you in control of how the data nodes are returned; reason I ask is I was wondering if you could wrap each expanded and abbre node in their own data node? If you could then your code above would work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you clean up your XSLT and  use `xsl:apply-templates` rather than `xsl:for-each`, life will become simpler. There is almost never a reason to use `xsl:for-each`. Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <head><title>Abbreviate</title></head>
            <body>
                <table border="1">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Expanded</th>
                        <th>Abbre</th>
                    </tr>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select='SSI/data/expanded'/>
                </table>
            </body></html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="expanded">
        <tr>
            <td><xsl:apply-templates/></td>
            <xsl:apply-templates select='following-sibling::abbre[1]'/>
        </tr>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="abbre">
        <td><xsl:apply-templates/></td>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

By using small templates that are applied, you simplify your stylesheet. Additionally, there is no real reason to use `xsl:value-of` here - the built-in templates will do the right thing. You will end up with simpler templates that are easier to understand.

Comment: +1 Better answer. I would name `abbre` matching rule as `makeCell` and call it from `expanded` matching rule, or even make this an "any element under `makeCell` mode" rule and apply template to self and following in `expanded` matching rule.

Comment: @Alejandro - yeah, thought about something similar and went for the simplest approach that I could that would only use `xsl:apply-templates`

Comment: Thanks Nic. I got the expected output.

Comment: I got output through your solution, thanks a lot for your help.