# Conversion from XML Data to XForms using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xforms

I want to visualise a bulk of data in an XML format, I found that xForms is a good choice for this purpose. while I'm googling it I found that xslt is a tool to transform between xml formats ( xforms among others). 
My goal is just to view my xml data in xforms.

I wrote the following code to do transformation. but I'm facing a lot of troubles.

```
        <head>
        <xforms:model id="my model">
        <xforms:instance xmlns="" id="i" src="file.xml">
        </xforms:instance>
        </xforms:model>    
        </head>
            <body>
                <h2>LIST</h2>
                <table border="1">
                    <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
                        <th>"year"</th>
                        <th>"Count_Student"</th>
                        <th>"a50_60"</th>
                    </tr>
                    <xsl:for-each select="Statistics">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <xsl:value-of select="year"/>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <xsl:value-of select="Count_Student"/>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <xsl:value-of select="a50_60"/>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </table>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

where the file "file.xml" contains the following

```
    <Statistics>
    <year>2005_2006</year>
       <Count_Student>2</Count_Student>
       <a50_60>1</a50_60>
    </Statistics>
```

When executing that code, nothing is depicted.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you are missing the top part of your XSLT (which could contain important information about why nothing is being output!). Also, is that an accurate representation of your XML, as your XSLT contains an **xsl:for-each** on the **Statistics** element, suggesting you expect more than one, but in your XML **Statistics** is the root element, so there will only ever be one. Thanks!

Comment: You don't need XForms to visualize XML. Transforming it to (X)HTML using XSLT is sufficient. Transforming XML to HTML is covered by http://stackoverflow.com/q/15956220/342546 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/4724700/342546.

Comment: Please add information **how** you tried to *execute the code*.

Comment: thanks, I tried it using eXide editor. a built in editor which comes with eXist-db.
for visualising, I need xForms because I have a library that works fine with XForms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can build the table using pure XForms without XSLT:

```
<table border="1">
  <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
    <th>"year"</th>
    <th>"Count_Student"</th>
    <th>"a50_60"</th>
  </tr>
  <xforms:repeat nodeset="Statistics">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <xforms:output ref="year" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <xforms:output ref="Count_Student" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <xforms:output ref="a50_60" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </xforms:repeat>
</table>
```

Comment: With very simple xml input, use direct Xforms as Bill showed you. But if you got complex input, keep on going with XSLT to produce instances fitting your xforms. We're doing that and it's quite powerful, imho.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following xslt code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs" version="2.0">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <head>
                <title>List output</title>
            </head>
            <body>
                <h2>LIST</h2>
                <table border="1">
                    <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
                        <th>"year"</th>
                        <th>"Count_Student"</th>
                        <th>"a50_60"</th>
                    </tr>
                    <xsl:for-each select="Statistics">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <xsl:value-of select="year"/>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <xsl:value-of select="Count_Student"/>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <xsl:value-of select="a50_60"/>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </table>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```